# как сделать кнопку в discordpy

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())
# Create a class called MyView that subclasses discord.ui.View
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    # Create a button with the label " Click me!" with color Blurple
    @discord.ui.button(label="Click me!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, emoji="")
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You clicked the button!")
@bot.command()
async def pon(ctx):

  await ctx.send('ticet',view=MyView())
bot.run(token)
```

вот код и он не работает я не знаю почему

Answer (score 2):

Вы использовали устаревшие примеры. Лично я использую вот так:

```
class Button(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(*, callback=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if callback:
            self.callback = callback

view = discord.ui.View()
view.add_item(
    Button(
        # Параметры кнопки
    )
)
await ctx.send('Сообщение с кнопкой', view=view)
```

Класс который я написал в начале призван ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО упросить запись `callback`-функции (на вход передаётся корунтинная функция с аргументом `Interaction`)

Вы можете обойтись без него:

```
view = discord.ui.View()

btn = discord.ui.Button(
    # Параметры кнопки
)
btn.callback = корунтинная функция # Можно не писать, если вам не нужно

view.add_item(btn)

await ctx.send('Сообщение с кнопкой', view=view)
```

Comment: а можете предоставить приер использования даного алгоритма со значениями @mister_svinia

Comment: Могу. Но за вашу психику после моих костылей не ручаюсь. https://disk.yandex.ru/d/F_3O7WqQrUTTow

Comment: Там не все возможности работы с кнопками, но для примера - сойдёт. `reports` - модуль в котором я храню модальные окна.